# How to print a vim list to file in ['l', 'i', 's', 't'] format?

Tags: vim

Today I learnt that I can use register `=` to print vim variables to file. However I got some trouble when trying to print a list to file.

```
# Command mode
:let L = [1, 2, 3]
:echo L

[1, 2, 3]

# Normal mode
"=L<C-M>p
1
2
3
```

How could I write the value of `L` into current file in a `[1, 2, 3]` format then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In command mode:

```
:put =string(L)
```

`string(expr)` function convert `expr` to a String. See [:help string()](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#string()) for more details.